# Tracking memory leak when using producer consumer paradigm in a bounded buffer

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-management, valgrind, producer-consumer

My program is supposed to "mince" bytes, or write bytes into an output file with the randomness of multi threading. Come execution, it stays in an infinite loop until I have to `ctrl-c`. This is what Valgrind gives me:

```
==685386== Process terminating with default action of signal 2 (SIGINT)
==685386==    at 0x4E4F66D: __pthread_timedjoin_ex (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.28.so)
==685386==    by 0x400F8D: main (bytemincer.c:85)
==685386== 
==685386== HEAP SUMMARY:
==685386==     in use at exit: 925 bytes in 4 blocks
==685386==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 6 frees, 19,365 bytes allocated
==685386== 
==685386== 5 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 4
==685386==    at 0x4C360A5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:380)
==685386==    by 0x401199: rb_init (ringbuf.c:23)
==685386==    by 0x400CC8: main (bytemincer.c:27)
==685386== 
==685386== 160 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 4
==685386==    at 0x4C360A5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:380)
==685386==    by 0x401177: rb_init (ringbuf.c:20)
==685386==    by 0x400CC8: main (bytemincer.c:27)
==685386== 
==685386== 272 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3 of 4
==685386==    at 0x4C3ADBB: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1117)
==685386==    by 0x40129EB: _dl_allocate_tls (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so)
==685386==    by 0x4E4EDD2: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.28.so)
==685386==    by 0x400F22: main (bytemincer.c:77)
==685386== 
==685386== 488 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 4
==685386==    at 0x4C360A5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:380)
==685386==    by 0x50D700E: __fopen_internal (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)
==685386==    by 0x401014: producer (bytemincer.c:104)
==685386==    by 0x4E4E179: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.28.so)
==685386==    by 0x5162DC2: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)
==685386== 
==685386== LEAK SUMMARY:
==685386==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==685386==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==685386==      possibly lost: 272 bytes in 1 blocks
==685386==    still reachable: 653 bytes in 3 blocks
==685386==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

The errors happen deep into the producer consumer threads, and it stops midway. These are where the errors occur:

```
-----
rb = rb_init(5); /* initializing ring buffer with size 5 */
-----

/* rb_init func */
struct ringbuf_t* rb_init(int bufsiz)
{
  struct ringbuf_t* rb;

  if(bufsiz <= 1) return 0; /* bufsiz must be greater than 1 */

  rb = (struct ringbuf_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct ringbuf_t)); /* LINE 20 */
  if(!rb) return 0; /* problem with memory allocation */

  rb->buf = (char*)malloc(bufsiz); /* LINE 23 */
  if(!rb->buf) return 0; /* problem with memory allocation */

  pthread_mutex_init(&rb->mutex, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&rb->cond_full, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&rb->cond_empty, NULL);
  rb->bufsiz = bufsiz;
  rb->front = rb->back = 0;

  return rb;
}
```

This is how I use `pthread_create` and `pthread_join`. It's supposed to be multiple producers and one consumer at work:

```
 /* populating thread for input/output file */
    pthread_t pt_ids[argc], ct_id;

    /* creates threads by passing struct as params */
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        pthread_create(&pt_ids[i], NULL, producer, (void*)&threads[i]); /* LINE 77 */

    pthread_create(&ct_id, NULL, consumer, (void*)rb);

    /* waits for the other threads to terminate */
    pthread_join(ct_id, &x);        
    
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        pthread_join(pt_ids[i], &x);
    
    rb_finalize(rb); /* frees ring buffer and ringbuf_t rb struct */
```

And finally,
this is my `producer` function:

```
void *producer(void *arg) {

    /* breaking apart thread data into variables for use */
    struct thread_data *data = (struct thread_data *)arg;

    FILE *fp;
    int c;

    fp = fopen(data->file_name, "r+");

    /* read each char from input file and insert into ring buffer */
    c = fgetc(fp);
    do {
        rb_insert(data->rb, c);
        // printf("inserted %c into buffer\n", c);
        c = fgetc(fp);
    } while (c != EOF);
    rb_insert(data->rb, -1);

    // printf("I MADE IT HERE: PRODUCER\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

And my `consumer` function:

```
void *consumer(void *arg) {

    /* breaking apart output thread data into variables for use */
    struct ringbuf_t *rb = (struct ringbuf_t *)arg;

    int c;

    /* collect last char of ring buffer and write to output file */
    c = rb_remove(rb);
    while (c != -1) {
        fputc(c, outputFile);
        // printf("put %c into output file!\n", c);
        c = rb_remove(rb);
    }
    printf("I MADE IT HERE: CONSUMER\n");
    // fclose(outputFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Anyone know what the memory leak could be a result of?

Comment: Please show minimum reproducible example. At least show definition of `rb_remove`

Comment: You've asked this question twice now. Make sure that your code is thread safe. Use DRD or Helgrind (part of Valgrind) or thread sanitizer. If your memory is corrupted because of thread hazards then all sorts of things can happen, like leaks and hangs.